# Is there a way to perform a one way function on encrypted data?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Does the following scheme exist?

Let f be a one-way function (say, an encryption scheme). Let $Enc_{sk}(x)$ be an encryption of x. We then have $Eval_{pk}(f, Enc_{sk}(x)) = f(x)$.

Note that this is not homomorphic encryption since in that case, $Eval_{pk}(f, Enc_{sk}(x)) = Enc_{sk}(f(x))$.

Comment: To what degree is Enc secure? What are the roles of sk and pk? Does the Enc and Eval have to support arbitrary functions f? Is this scheme used as part of a larger scheme?

Comment: Clearly such a scheme would not be CPA secure. So what security are you looking for?

Comment: Actually, if $Eval$ can be applied to any $f$, then by setting $f$ to the identity function $f(x) = x$, the original value of $x$ can be recovered from $Enc_{sk}(x)$, which means that it isn't quite 'one-way'.

Comment: As has already been mentioned, such a scheme is not secure if evaluating arbitrary f can be done publicly. It sounds like the closest thing to what you want is functional encryption, which allows for the distribution of secret keys $sk_f$ associated with a function $f$. You can then run a 'decryption' algorithm that looks like: $Dec(sk_f, Enc_{sk}(x)) = f(x)$